# PIVOT with multiple rows result and duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I need your suggestions on this.

I want to pivot this rows to a column with the result that have multiple duplicated rows

Before:

| line_type | line_name |
| --- | --- |
| Internal | Storage 1 |
| Makloon | Storage 2 |
| Internal | Storage 1 |
| Makloon | Storage 3 |
| Process | Storage B |
| Makloon | Storage 3 |

After:

| Internal | Makloon | Process |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Storage 1 | Storage 2 | Storage B |
| Storage 1 | Storage 3 |  |
|  | Storage 3 |  |

Can I use pivot or is there another trick to do this?

I have tried using regular pivot but it just doesn't work like what I wanted.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        [line_type],
        [line_name]
    FROM 
        [table_name]
) pvt
PIVOT (
    MAX(line_name)
    FOR [line_type] IN (
        [Internal],
        [Makloon],
        [Process]
    )
) AS pvt_table;
```

The result of that PIVOT query  I tried:

| Internal | Makloon | Process |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Storage 1 | Storage 3 | Storage B |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Phrases like `doesn't work like what I wanted` don't help, they're truly awful.  Please, instead, include in your question a demonstration of what you ***did*** want.  *(Please read the link provided above for full details.)*

Comment: You just undid my edits which formatted your question. Please don't.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time asking a question

Comment: You cannot get the output you're asking for unless you make some of the rows distinct from each other. We cannot do this for you as we don't know how you need to split/differentiate your rows. Consider adding a ID column to your table, which identifies the sets, and then running the PIVOT.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep your rows separated, you need a distinct value. One way is to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to assign distinct values within each pivot column.

Something like:

```
SELECT rn, [Internal], [Makloon], [Process]
FROM (
    SELECT
        [line_type],
        [line_name],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY line_type ORDER BY line_name) AS rn
    FROM 
        [table_name]
) pvt
PIVOT (
    MAX(line_name)
    FOR [line_type] IN (
        [Internal],
        [Makloon],
        [Process]
    )
) AS pvt_table
ORDER BY rn;
```

`rn` can be dropped from the final select list. It was placed there for illustration purposes.

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Km_xg_OM).